# Adding library project to Android.mk

Tags: android, android-make

My project (A) is dependent on two library projects (B & C). B & C have java sources & resources (layouts, drawables, values).

If I want to build A, I need to include B & C in the Android.mk of A.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on project A from Package Explorer, then click on Properties --> Java Build Path --> Projects --> Add. Add library projects B and C from here. No need to include them on Manifest. Import classes which you want to use on project A's class.

Comment: I want to specify them in the make file (Android.mk) to build along with AOSP. Your answer is not related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Projects (B & C) to your product's `PRODUCT_PACKAGES +=` list, so they will be built for sure.